# AttributeError: in Python program that chooses information from a list

Tags: python, list, attributeerror

I have a fairly simple Python program that is supposed to prompt the user to choose:

1. show an alphabetical list of all the states, their capitols, and Flowers.
2. show a specific state with its bird.
3. update a bird for a specific state.
4. exit.

My problem is with the 2 option. When I select option 2 and type in a state it will give this error:

```
in display_data
print("State name: ", state_data.state_name, " , Capital: ", state_data.capital, " , Bird: ", state_data.bird)
AttributeError: 'state' object has no attribute 'bird'
```

Below is the code. I only choose the first two states data to save space.

```
class state:

    def __init__(self, state_name, capital, flower):
        self.state_name = state_name
        self.capital = capital
        self.flower = flower


    def update_bird(self, bird):
        self.bird = bird


def update_bird_for_State(state_list_bird, state_name, bird_name):
    for state in state_list_bird:
        if state.state_name == state_name:
            state.update_bird(bird_name)

def display_sorted_states(state_list_flower):
    for state in sorted([state.state_name for state in  state_list_flower]):
        for state_data in state_list_flower:
            if state == state_data.state_name:
                print("State name: ", state_data.state_name, " , Capital: ", state_data.capital, " , Flower: ", state_data.flower)

def display_data(state_list_bird, state):
    data_found = False
    for state_data in state_list_bird:
        if state_data.state_name == state:
            data_found = True
            print("State name: ", state_data.state_name, " , Capital: ", state_data.capital, " , Bird: ", state_data.bird)

if data_found == False:
    print("No data found.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    state_list_flower = []

    s = state('Alabama','Montgomery', 'Camellia')
    state_list_flower.append(s)

    s = state('Alaska','Juneau', 'Forget Me Not')
    state_list_flower.append(s)

    state_list_bird = []

    s = state('Alabama','Montgomery', 'Yellowhammer')
    state_list_bird.append(s)

    s = state('Alaska','Juneau', 'Willow Ptarmigan')
    state_list_bird.append(s)

    user_input = 1
    while(user_input in [1,2,3,4]):
        print("\n1. Display all U.S. States in Alphabetical order along with Capital and Flower")
        print("2. Search for a specific state and display the appropriate Capital and Bird")
        print("3. Update a Bird for a specific state")
        print("4. Exit the program")

        user_input = int(input("\nEnter choices: "))

        if(user_input == 1):
            display_sorted_states(state_list_flower)
        elif(user_input == 2 ):
            state_name = input("\nEnter State Name: ")
            display_data(state_list_bird, state_name)
        elif(user_input == 3):
            state_name = input("\nEnter State Name: ")
            bird_name = input("\nEnter Bird Name: ")
            update_bird_for_State(state_list_bird, state_name, bird_name)
        elif(user_input == 4 ):
            break
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Also, that means that `update_bird` is never called. You'd need to figure out why that's happening, or, give `self.bird` an initial value in `__init__`.

Comment: You appear to be trying to call `display_data` before calling `update_bird_for_State`.

Comment: Looking at the code and requirement, you can simply add the bird into __init__ and then once the objects are created and added to the list along with the bird, then you can search for a bird based on the specified state in the option-2 so that the object is available.

Comment: The update_bird_for_State option runs correctly. However when option 2 is selected and a state is entered it will error out. When I add self.bird = bird to init and try option 2 and enter a state it will return with an error for undefined variable.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be bird not defined in your state class under init, thus there is no such variable as state.bird in class state.

```
class state:

    def __init__(self, state_name, capital, flower, bird):
        self.state_name = state_name
        self.capital = capital
        self.flower = flower
        self.bird = bird


    def update_bird(self, bird):
        self.bird = bird
```

Comment: When I add that and run it returns TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'bird'

Comment: I tried to update this section `def display_data(self, state_list_bird, state, bird):
    self.bird = bird
    data_found = False
    for state_data in state_list_bird:
        if state_data.state_name == state:
            data_found = True
            print("State name: ", state_data.state_name, " , Capital: ", state_data.capital, " , Bird: ", state_data.bird)
`  and it returned with TypeError: display_data() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'state' and 'bird'